# Function passed via completion block sometimes doesn't run...how to debug

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to debug the following code:

```
- (void) getAllDataForHKIdentifier {
...
void (^completionCopy)(NSArray *) = [completion copy];
...

    HKAnchoredObjectQuery *newQuery = [[HKAnchoredObjectQuery alloc] initWithType:quantityType predicate:predicate anchor:anchor limit:HKObjectQueryNoLimit resultsHandler:^(HKAnchoredObjectQuery * _Nonnull query, NSArray<__kindof HKSample *> * _Nullable sampleObjects, NSArray<HKDeletedObject *> * _Nullable deletedObjects, HKQueryAnchor * _Nullable newAnchor, NSError * _Nullable error) {

                if([sampleObjects count] > 0){
                    NSLog(@"for hkquantity type = %@ is block null? %d is block nil? %d those are the answers", theHKIdentifier, [completion isKindOfClass: [NSNull class]], completion==nil);

                    NSLog(@"here is direct call to nonsense");
                    [self nonsenseTestFunc:sampleObjects];

                    // this often fails to run although completion block is neither nil nor NSNull so far as I can tell
                    NSLog(@"here is completion object %@", completion);
                    completionCopy(sampleObjects);

                    NSLog(@"tktktk for source %@ there are %d sources and those sources are %@", useSource, (int)[sampleObjects count], sampleObjects);
                }


                [[ODLogManager sharedManager] logString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tktktk setting anchor from %@ to %@ for category %@ when results count is %d", anchor, newAnchor, theHKIdentifier, (int)[sampleObjects count]] forCategory:ODLoggingAileen];
                [[CoreManager sharedManager] setHealthKitAnchorForIdentifier:theHKIdentifier toValue:newAnchor];
            }];

            [healthStore executeQuery:newQuery];

...
}
```

This code above is in a function called by the following function within the same class instance:

```
            dispatch_group_async(dispatchGroup, queue, ^{
                    [self getAllDataForHKIdentifier: hkType withCompletion:^(NSArray *results) {
                    [self nonsenseTestFunc:results];
                }];
            });
```

The above is the only place I call `getAllDataForHKIdentifier` so the completionCopy block should also run this `nonsenseTestFunc`. But right now it only runs it about half the time that the rest of the code within the `if` statement runs. The other half of the time when the other statements in the control statement are run, there is no sign that `completionCopy` has run.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- As you can see from the log statements, I've tried checking whether the completion black is nil or NSNull, but these both return false. Is there another way to determine that the completion block is faulty or to determine the contents of the completion block?
- I thought there could be some memory-overwriting issue / leak issue even though I'm using ARC, so I make a copy of the `completion` parameter and then run this copy within the query's call rather than the original block. This has not changed the bug.

Any ideas why this would be happening? **Seems like the `completion` block must be getting lost or nil-ed somewhere along the line, but how or why?** Thanks for any input.

Comment: No need to check if the block is nil or null - it would crash if you called it, so you didn't call it.

Comment: @gnasher729 but I want to know why completionCopy is not running, so if it turned out to be nil or null I would know why it's not running. Right now there is no sign of it running even though it tests as not being nil or null.

Comment: It's not going to spontaneously turn into an `NSNull`. That class is a "no value" placeholder in collections, usually when they're deserialized from somewhere else. It doesn't just pop up in one of your variables for no apparent reason.

Comment: What is the completion Block supposed to do? What are the "signs" that it has run? Have you tried substituting a dumb stand-in that just logs its argument, or even throws an exception so it's very noticeable?

Comment: @JoshCaswell yes I have tried substituting in a dumb standing that just logs an argument. That log argument never appears even though the other log statements in the if block do appear.

Answer (score -1):

The only call to completionCopy is within if (samplesObjects.count > 0). So obviously it doesn't get called if that count is zero.

Comment: Maybe my question didn't make it clear, but I am talking about when the other portions within the if statement run, sometimes completionCopy(...) doesn't run.